# What does this line means in a shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, ubuntu

What does this line means in a shell script?

```
THIS_SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(...)` means run the command within and return the output as a string. `=`, as you probably already know, assigns a string to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

It assigns the path of the script to variable THIS_SCRIPT.
I checked the readlink manpage, the -f option follows the symlinks in path (if they exist)